# Present Simple VS Pres. Continious

Tags: grammar, word-usage, tenses, present-tense

In this exercise I have to put verbs in correct tense (Present Simple VS Continous). I did not get why the correct form us "HE FINALLY CHOOSES", not he is finally choosing? It is not applied to the rule of habits or repeated actions.

[image]

Comment: Simple Present Tense can describe events, not only states and habits. You can use it like this when you have a series of events, as in this passage. It is especially natural when the verb refers to a short action - we would rather expect that the event of choosing something happens momentarily. The present progressive wouldn't sit well in this context. The meaning of "chooses"in this context is perfective - he has chosen the test. (present perfect "has chosen" is a possible atlernative)

Comment: The whole passage is understood like a live report, like from a football game. You would narrate something like this only if you're observing someone in real time and reporting their every move. Not something that people do a lot in reality.